# If something costs 45 euros and I will have 100 euro note how to say that I'll need 55 euro back(change)?

Tags: phrase-request

From googling I don't see that it's common to say 'I need change from 100 euros'.

So what's the proper way to say this?

Comment: In general, when we buy things, the seller is responsible for calculating the change. If you gave 100 euros for an item which cost 45 euros, and the seller only gave you 50 euros, you could say "the change from 100 euros should be 55 euros".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey yes, it's common sense, but I'm pre-booking taxi in another country so want to make sure that driver will have change. So, I can say 'Driver should have change from 100 euros', right?

Comment: Yes, or you could say "Will the driver be able to give change from 100 euros?"

Comment: I would say "please bring change of 10 and 5 euro notes !" but I am not native

Comment: Or you could say "I will be paying with a 100 euro note, so the driver should have change / be prepared"

Comment: Just be straightforward instead of trying to say something else; say "I will only have 100 Euro notes so can you please bring enough smaller change?"